# Trouble navigating an Angular form to access it's controls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

**Preface:**

I am having the hardest time trying to figure out what sounds like an easy process for nested angular forms. I am dealing with a few components here and some of the `formGroups` and `formArrays` are being dynamically created and its throwing me off.

Apologies for the large code dump, but its the minimal example I was able to come up with to try and explain my problem.

---

The parent component is very straight forward as it only has two `formControls`. I then pass the form to the `tasks` component to have access to it.

### Parent Component

```
this.intakeForm = this.fb.group({
   requestor: ['', Validators.required],
   requestJustification: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]=“intakeForm”>

<app-tasks 
    [uiOptions]="uiOptions"
    [intakeForm]="intakeForm">
</app-tasks>

</form>
```

### Tasks Component

Some method in here will trigger `generateTask` which creates the new form group.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.intakeForm.addControl('tasks', new FormArray([]));
}

// Push a new form group to our tasks array
generateTask(user, tool) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.intakeForm.controls['tasks'];
    control.push(this.newTaskControl(user, tool))
}

// Return a form group
newTaskControl(user, tool) {
    return this.fb.group({
      User: user,
      Tool: tool,
      Roles: this.fb.array([])
    })    
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-condensed smallText" *ngIf="intakeForm.controls['tasks'].length">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Role(s)</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let t of intakeForm.get('tasks').controls let i = index; trackBy:trackByIndex" [taskTR]="t" [ui]="uiOptions" [intakeForm]="intakeForm" [taskIndex]="i">
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

### TR Component

Some method in here will trigger the `addRole` method which will add the form group.

```
@Input('taskTR') row;
@Input('ui') ui;
@Input('intakeForm') intakeForm: FormGroup;

// Add a new role
addRole($event, task) {
   let t = task.get('Roles').controls as FormArray;
   t.push(this.newRoleControl($event))
}

// Return a form group
newRoleControl(role) {
   return this.fb.group({
     Role: [role, Validators.required],
     Action: [null, Validators.required]
   })
 }
```

HTML

```
<td class="col-md-9">
    <ng-select  [items]="ui.adminRoles.options" 
                bindLabel="RoleName" 
                bindValue="Role"
                placeholder="Select one or more roles" 
                [multiple]="true"
                [clearable]="false" 
                (add)="addRole($event, row)" 
                (remove)="removeRole($event, row)">
</td>
```

### The Question

I need to add `formControlName` to my `TR Component`, specifically on the `ng-select`. However, when I try and add a `formControlName`, it tells me that it needs to be within a `formGroup`.

From what I can tell, the `formGroup` is in the `tasksComponent` and is wrapping the whole table so its technically within a `formGroup`?

My end goal is to be able to add the `formControlName` to this input but I am having a hard time trying to figure out the path to get there.

Here is an image of the full form object.
The last expanded section, `Role`, is what this input should be called via `formControlName` so that I can perform validation and what not on the control.

[image]

### Updates

Edit 1 - Changes for @Harry Ninh

Tasks Component HTML

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let t of intakeForm.get('tasks').controls let i = index; trackBy:trackByIndex" [taskTR]="t" [ui]="uiOptions" [intakeForm]="intakeForm" [taskIndex]="i" [formGroup]="intakeForm"></tr>
</tbody>
```

TR Component HTML

```
<td class="col-md-9">
  <ng-select  [items]="ui.adminRoles.options" 
              bindLabel="RoleName" 
              bindValue="Role"
              placeholder="Select one or more roles" 
              [multiple]="true"
              [clearable]="false" 
              formControlName="Roles"
              (add)="addRole($event, row)" 
              (remove)="removeRole($event, row)">
</td>
```

Result: `ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.`

Comment: I didn't see any `[formGroup]="intakeForm` in your code. Is there something missing?

Comment: @HarryNinh - So the formGroup is missing from this example but it is included. It is in the parent component and wraps the tasksComponent. That is what is them passed into the tasksComponent.

Answer (score 2):

You are expected to declare `[formGroup]="intakeForm"` in the root tag of every component that wraps all `formControlName`, `formGroupName` and `formArrayName` properties. Angular won't try to go up the hierarchy to find that when compiling the code.

Comment: So i need to put it in the tasksComponent on the <table>. Then it’s passed into the TR component. Do i then need to declare it in the TR component html? I wanna say i tried this but i then gave the ng-select a formControlName and it said the path wasn’t found. I guess my confusion comes from how to declare everything that is needed in the TR component html so that my input is in the correct place within the hierarchy. For example, do i need to declare the form arrays as well? Not sure where to put all that while keeping the html table valid all within the TD

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that you were not about to add `formControlName` in `TasksComponent`. Just edited my answer. So you are using `formControlName` in TR component, you should add `[formGroup]="..."` in the root tag of TR component. And if you don't use any `formControlName` in Tasks component, you won't need to change it.

Comment: I got an error when I tried this. Updated the OP with the details for your suggestion.

Comment: No that wasn't what I meant, sorry if my answer is not clear enough. The idea is, within ONE HTML document, if you use `formControlName`, you must have `[formGroup]="..."`.

Answer (score 1):

In TR Component template, the root element (ie. the `<td>`) should have `[formGroup]="intakeForm"`, in order to tell Angular the `formControlName` who is related to.

Comment: When I added this, I get the following error: `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'Roles'`.